# setTimeout() function runs without delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, recursion, settimeout

I have a program where a html button calls a jQuery function (call it funcOne). That function in turn calls a recursive function (call it funcTwo) that changes some CSS in the DOM. funcTwo contains two setTimeout() calls to delay the CSS changes, creating a sort of blinking effect.

funcOne looks something like this:

```
function funcOne(stringOfNumbers){

    //This function does some other stuff that does not interfere with funcTwo
    someUnrelatedFunction(); 

    funcTwo(time);

    return;
}
```

funcTwo looks something like this:

```
function funcTwo(time){

    if(time == ""){return true;}

    var delay = time.charAt(0);
    var numDelay = parseInt(delay);

    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#container").css("background-color", "white");
        console.log("Changed to white");
    }, 1000); //Arbitrary delay

    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#container").css("background-color", "black");
        console.log("Changed to black");
    }, numDelay); //Variable delay

    time = time.substr(1);

    return funcTwo(time);

}
```

The console shows both messages, so I know the script is running. I'm not getting any stack overflow errors.
However, both delays (arbitrary and variable) do not run. The #container immediately turns black.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem I see is that the most delay you are allowing before it changes to black is 9 milliseconds. Since you are giving the second variable delay the value of the first character of the time variable, which the greatest 1 character number is 9. If you wish to run the background color to white first, I would move the second `setTimeout()` to inside the first `setTimeout()` to allow it to only be prepared to run after the background is white. `setTimeout()` is prepared and does not immediately run the function. This allows, in your code, the code after `setTimeout()` to be run before the function is actually ran.

Comment: I notice one more issue: If I add another unrelated function after func2 (so func1 now has 3 function calls), the time delay is yet again ignored. How should I resolve this?

Comment: While this is true, the background should be changed to white after 1s

Comment: @nucleic550 you would then put more setTimeout functions inside of funcOne, or trigger the new setTimeout inside of funcTwo

Answer (score 0):

The Set Time setTimeout() has two parameters first paramater is a callback function and the second is timeInterval in  miliseconds. so in you case you set it as 1000 which is 1 second. and exactly run after 1 second.

```
 setTimeout(function(){

        alert("Changed to white");
    }, 1000);
```